# Pseudo selector :last-child not working

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm using a navbar in Bootstrap 4 and I can't figure out how to apply  `border-right` to `nav-link` excepting the last item.

Here is my HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-transparent">

<button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">

    <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>

        </li>
    </ul>

</div>
</nav>
```

AND SCSS:

```
.navbar {
  .navbar-nav {
     .nav-link {
        border-right:1px solid red;
        &:last-child {
           border-right:none;
        }
      }
   }
}
```

I don't know why but this example removes all borders from `nav-link` instead of the last one.

I want to achieve this without javascript or a specific class ! Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All your `nav-link` are the last child to the parent element. Try this instead. Also not that it doesn't have to be this specific but I assume you know about specificity so I'll keep it as is.

```
.navbar {
  .navbar-nav {
     .nav-link {
        border-right:1px solid red;
      }

     li {
       &:last-of-type {
          .nav-link {
             border-right:none;
          }
        }
     }
   }
}
```

Note that you have a stray closing `li` element.

Answer (score 1):

`:last-child` should be target to `nav-item` instead of

Change your code SCSS become:

```
.navbar {
  .navbar-nav {
    .nav-link {
      border-right:1px solid red;
    }
    .nav-item {
      &:last-child {
        .nav-link {
          border-right:none;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```